# How to call a command from window pop in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, command, datacontext, function-call

How call a delegate command from window pop up.
I'm showing a pop up window over a window..
The pop up window have button which need to call `DelegateCommand` from ViewModel.

Below is the code for Window > **MyPopUp.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MyPopUp : Window
{
  public MyPopUp(){
     InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Below is the code for ViewModel> > **MyPopUpViewModel.cs**

```
public class MyPopUpViewModel: BindableBase
{
    public MyPopUpViewModel()
    {
        AddCommand = new DelegateCommand(AddCommandCall);

    }

    private void AddCommandCall()
    {
        /// Command call Code here
    }

    public DelegateCommand AddCommand { get; private set; }

}
```

**MyPopUp.xaml** code here

```
<Window x:Class="Project"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"

      xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Project.PopUpControls"
    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
     xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"

    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Create Levels" Height="700" Width="900" 
    prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">

<Grid>
    <Button
        Command="{Binding DataContext.AddCommand}"            
        Content="test"
        Margin="0,5,0,0"
        FontSize="16"
        FontWeight="Normal"
        Width="100"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
        Foreground="#ffffff"
        Background="#4e4e4e"/>
</Grid>
```

Though when **`InitializeComponent();`** is called in **MyPopUp.xaml.cs**  the window **DataContext** get all the commands in it from **MyPopUpViewModel.cs**

Then when clicked on button on pop up... It should call the command **AddCommand**, but it is not getting called.

Let me know what I'm missing or sommnething need to be added/change.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Digging for so much time on wpf and trying some alternative.. i got the answer `Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.AddCommand,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"`

```
<Grid>
<Button
    Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.AddCommand,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"            
    Content="test"
    Margin="0,5,0,0"
    FontSize="16"
    FontWeight="Normal"
    Width="100"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
    Foreground="#ffffff"
    Background="#4e4e4e"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see in your codebehind or in xaml the call to your viewmodel. Maybe i'm wrong but for me you need to call after InitializeComponent() in codebehind ==> DataContext = new MyPoPupViewModel() !

Xaml call :

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourApplication"

<Window.DataContext>
   <local:MyPoPupViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. Here the company is following the rule., that not to write codebehind code,,,

Comment: That's very weird...it's not really the codebehind it's the constructor !! So call it in .xaml :                                                                                   <Window.DataContext>
       <local:MyPopupViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

Answer (score 0):

Please set DataContext for View

```
InitializeComponent();
DataContext = new MyPopUpViewModel();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. Here the company is following the rule., that not to write codebehind code,,,

Comment: then, you can use VoewModel Locator for set DataContext